# How to re-name a file with the directory name using powershell

Tags: powershell, rename, file-rename

I have a folder with images in that I need re-naming.

Currently the files are like this:

```
C:\Images\Today\4714\IMG_2342.jpg
C:\Images\Today\4714\IMG_2343.jpg
C:\Images\Today\4714\IMG_2344.jpg
C:\Images\Today\4714\IMG_2345.jpg
```

And I need them to be like this:

```
C:\Images\Today\4714\4714_1.jpg
C:\Images\Today\4714\4714_2.jpg
C:\Images\Today\4714\4714_3.jpg
C:\Images\Today\4714\4714_4.jpg
```

How can I do this in powershell please?

Comment: Have you tried this other post solution
- how do I rename a bunch of files in the command prompt
http://superuser.com/questions/347931/how-do-i-rename-a-bunch-of-files-in-the-command-prompt

Answer (score 1):

If you know that no files named `4714_X.jpg` exist already, you can easily do this with a for loop:

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem C:\Images\Today\4714\ *.jpg
for($i = 0; $i -lt $Files.Count; $i++)
{
    Rename-Item $Files[$i].FullName -NewName "4714_$i.jpg"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to do this:

```
Rename-Item C:\Images\Today\4714\IMG_2342.jpg C:\Images\Today\4714\IMG_2343.jpg  C:\Images\Today\4714\4714_1.jpg C:\Images\Today\4714\4714_2.jpg
```

if your having trouble you can check this [website](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176940.aspx) , gives you all you need to know

if you want to make script for all of the files to be renamed , I suggest to use regExp to catch the IMG_num and to replace it with what ever you want.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
dir C:\Images\Today\4714\ *.jpg | ? {$_.name -NotMatch "^$($_.directory.name)"} | % {ren $_.fullname $($_.name -replace 'img(?=_)', $_.directory.name)}
```